# Backlight controls stop working once X starts

Tags: 12.04, drivers, ati, brightness, backlight

I'm using a Lenovo Thinkpad X120e with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit and a Gnome 3.4 (gnome-shell) desktop environment. I have installed the latest proprietary AMD drivers (From their website) for the AMD Radeon HD 6250 graphics card.

My problem is that once the mouse appears on the screen at startup, the backlight controls (Fn+Delete/Home) stop working. While it's booting up, I can control the brightness just fine. At first it wouldn't work at all, but turning off Vari-Bright in Catalyst Control Center fixed it. Once logged in the OSD works fine, but brightness control does not work, so it's no a keyboard shortcut issue. I have tried adding `acpi_backlight=vendor`, `acpi_backlight=video`, `acpi_osi=Linux`, `acpi_osi=`, and combinations of the two options to the grub config and they do not do anything (of course I ran `grub-update`). I have also tried adding `Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"` to the `Device` section of xorg.conf (I belive this is for Nvidia drivers, but doesn't hurt to try), and combined this with the grub configs, and this also does nothing.

I am running out of options here. It's not so bad, but quite annoying during the evening when I want to turn the brightness down.

Anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev*
```

Remove your xorg.conf file:

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Re-install xorg:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 xserver-xorg-core
```

Configure xorg:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```

And that should work!

It is all [here](http://ubuntutechnical.wordpress.com/2011/11/20/install-ati-official-drivers-in-ubuntu/).

Comment: I know this is a bit late, but thanks. That laptop is not running Ubuntu anymore (Installed Win8 and gave it to someone) , but if I ever have this problem again, I'll know what to do. That said, I'm sticking to Intel from now on.